# Структуры в C и C++

Tags: c++, c

Пишу на C++. Случайно наткнулся на такой код, хотелось бы узнать что здесь происходит и можно ли такое повторить на C++.

```
static struct pci_driver my_driver = {
    .name = "my_pci_driver",
    .id_table = my_driver_id_table,
    .probe = my_driver_probe,
    .remove = my_driver_remove
};
```

И еще - зачем перед объявлением экземпляра структуры в C нужно указывать ключевое слово `struct`, а в C++ - нет?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> И еще - зачем перед объявлением экземпляра структуры в C нужно указывать ключевое слово struct, а в C++ - нет?

С и С++ - разные языки с разными правилами.

> хотелось бы узнать что здесь происходит

Это синтаксис инициализации с тегами (tagged initializers), введенный в язык С в стандарте С99. Что именно там происходит по-моему довольно очевидно: вы явно указываете какой член структуры хотите инициализировать каждым значением, тем самым делая инициализатор независимым от порядка объявления полей в структуре.

> можно ли такое повторить на C++

C++ пока не поддерживает синтаксис инициализации с тегами, и прямого аналога на уровне ядра языка нет. Если я не ошибаюсь, поддержка этого синтаксиса в некоей модифицированной/урезанной форме - [в планах для C++20](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0329r4.pdf). Ранее предложения поддержки этого синтаксиса в С++ упорно отвергались комитетом из-за сопутствующих сложностей, возникающих в контексте С++ инициализации.

Answer (score 0):

Компилятор g++ вполне позволяет так писать на с++. Но это является расширением языка и не входит в стандарт.